# "I want to compare the dates of second month" display all the dates of February(02)

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to compare the dates of 2nd month.
Display only dates that are in second month 
by using sql query

Comment: Hint: There's a Standard SQL `EXTRACT` function (or there's `BETWEEN`)

Comment: provide what have you tried so far? sql query or any input output table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this will help you:

```
SELECT BirthDate FROM Employees where EXTRACT(MONTH FROM BirthDate)=2;
```